# How to sort Firebase news article data by date in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

This is my part of my Firebase datastructure.
I want to sort each news by date.
So i searched on the internet and i found well organized document.(https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-reading-once)

But i don't know how can i reference each articles which is child node of news sites.

```
ref = database.getReference("news");
ref.(?).orderByChild("Pubdate").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

And i want to know how to convert "Pubdate" string to something that firebase can recognize when sorting.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing the date with the format you are using, use the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC).

You will get it by calling `System.currentTimeMillis()`

If you don't want to replace the data item with your current format, you can add another data item containing the Epoch time, as follows:

```
- -LBvaSIKGR....
    - author: "...."
    .....
    - pubdate: "Mon, 07 ...."
    - pubdateMillis: 1528536888
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but i also want to know how to reference each news. for example ,like this `DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/saving-data/fireblog/posts");`

Comment: Sorry but it is not 100% clear what you want to achieve. In your post you mention `database.getReference("news");` and here `database.getReference("server/saving-data/fireblog/posts");`. Can you be more precise and maybe add some details to your post.

Comment: Ah sorry ! that is code in the document i mentioned above. according to the document, in order to sort data(news article) by date i should  add eventlistener to specific data node. but i don't know how to reference the article node which has random key value.